# Can't getting same postname slug for multiple custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I have 2 Custom Post Type(Our Works and Case Study) in a WordPress site. If I add same postname(Pepsi) at my 2 Custom Post Type(Our Works and Case Study) the permalink will show given below:

1) www.example.com/our-works/pepsi/

2) www.example.com/case-study/pepsi-2/

But It should be like:

1) www.example.com/our-works/pepsi/

2) www.example.com/case-study/pepsi/

Comment: ...Can you not manually change the permalink on the edit screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for hours... I finally figured it out. Posting this for everyone who might encounter the same issue.

I have got 2 solutions:

- Install a plugin called [Allow Duplicate Slugs By John
  Blackbourn](https://github.com/johnbillion/allow-duplicate-slugs)
- Another one is Add a [function to function.php](http://www.cuberis.com/2013/07/wordpress-duplicate-slugs-for-different-post-types/)